# AutoHotKey: send Ctrl+V inside of itself without recursiving

Tags: recursion, autohotkey

I have this script, when I press Ctrl+Win+Z it runs a Paste (Ctrl+V), then if ScrollLock is enabled it flushes Clipboard, deleting the content I just pasted.

```
^#A::
    Send ^v
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T"){
        Clipboard = 
    }
    Return
```

Now I wanna bind this command to Ctrl+V itself. But when I do so, I receive a dialog saying that "71 hotkeys have been received in the last 1092ms" and asking if I wanna continue.

I believe it's recursiving on itself. Every `Send ^v` triggers the command again.

How can I do that work? I don't want the clear clipboard to be in another shortcut, because I might forget to use this other shortcut and use Ctrl+V instead. I wanna use standard Ctrl+V for pasting and ScrollLock to set when clipboard should be flushed after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` prefix [prevents hotkeys from triggering themselves](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols):

```
$^v:: ; ....
```